# Why it is contradicting?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, vectors, mathematical-physics, divergence-operator

Let:

$\nabla$ denote dell operator with respect to field coordinate (origin)

$\nabla'$ denote dell operator with respect to source coordinates

The electric field at origin due to an electric dipole distribution in volume $V$ having boundary $S$ is:

\begin{align}
\int_V \dfrac{(\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{r}) (\hat{r})}{r^3} dV
&=-\nabla \left(  \int_V \dfrac{\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{r}}{r^2} dV    \right)\\
&=-\nabla \left[  \int_V \mathbf{M} \cdot \nabla' \left( \dfrac{1}{r}  \right) dV  \right]\\
&=-\nabla \left[ - \int_V \dfrac{\nabla' \cdot \mathbf{M}}{r} dV 
+ \int_V  \nabla' \cdot  \left(\dfrac{\mathbf{M}}{r} \right) dV \right] \\
&=-\nabla \left(  \int_V \dfrac{-\nabla' \cdot \mathbf{M}}{r} dV + \oint_S \dfrac{\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{n}}{r} dS  \right)\\
&=\int_V \dfrac{-\nabla' \cdot \mathbf{M}}{r^2}(\hat{r}) dV + \oint_S \dfrac{\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{n}}{r^2} (\hat{r}) dS\\
\end{align}

In the above equation, we applied the vector identity $\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla\psi=-(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A})\psi + \nabla \cdot (\psi \mathbf{A})$ and the divergence theorem.

If the origin point is not on boundary $S$ but inside $V$:

> \begin{align}
> LHS&=\int_V \dfrac{(\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{r}) (\hat{r})}{r^3} dV\\
> &=\int_V \dfrac{(\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{r}) (\hat{r})}{r^3}\ r^2 \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi\ dr\\
> &=\int_V \dfrac{(\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{r}) (\hat{r})}{r}\ \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi\ dr\\
> \end{align}
>
> $(1)$ Here the integrand contains a singular point and hence the integral diverges.

$$\text{}$$

> \begin{align}
> RHS&=\int_V \dfrac{-\nabla' \cdot \mathbf{M}}{r^2}(\hat{r}) dV + \oint_S \dfrac{\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{n}}{r^2} (\hat{r}) dS\\
> &=\int_V \dfrac{-\nabla' \cdot \mathbf{M}}{r^2}(\hat{r})\ r^2 \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi\ dr
> + \oint_S \dfrac{\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{n}}{r^2} (\hat{r}) dS\\
> &=-\int_V \nabla' \cdot \mathbf{M}\ (\hat{r})\ \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi\ dr
> + \oint_S \dfrac{\mathbf{M} \cdot \hat{n}}{r^2} (\hat{r}) dS
> \end{align}
>
> $(2)$ Here both the integrands contain no singular point and hence the integrals converge.

$(1)$ and $(2)$ contradicts. Why is there such a contradiction?

Comment: You have two integrals (LHS =RHS), LHS diverges but RHS converges. That is the contradiction (is like getting $\infty=c$). Were you asking that? or maybe you want to know why LHS diverges and why RHS converges?

Comment: Yes.. I mean if LHS=RHS, either both should converge or both should diverge. But this is not happening. Why?